# Difference between probability and likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, probability, log-likelihood

I had to think through what it meant when I read that likelihood is not probability, but the following case occurred to me.

What is the likelihood that a coin is fair, given that we see four heads in a row?

We can't really say anything about probability here, but the word "trust" seems apt.

Do we feel we can trust the coin?

Found on internet.

Probability quantifies anticipation (of outcome), likelihood quantifies trust (in model).

I Can someone give clean explanation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming.  Try Math.SE or Stats.SE.  But search first because it may be an FAQ.

Comment: For example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability)

Answer (score 0):

**Probability** is the quantity most people are familiar with which deals with predicting new data given a known model ("what is the probability of getting heads six times in a row flipping this 50:50 coin?")

while, 
**Likelihood** deals with fitting models given some known data ("what is the likelihood that this coin is/isn't rigged given that I just flipped heads six times in a row?").

A likelihood quantity such as 0.12 is not meaningful to the layman unless it is explained exactly what 0.12 means: a measure of the sample's support for the assumed model i.e. low values either mean rare data or incorrect model!

"*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYxNSUDSFH4*" can be helpful